# NSPredicate CONTAINS but only when not empty

Tags: swift, core-data, nspredicate

It seems that with `NSPredicate(format: "name CONTAINS %@", name)`:

If `name` is not empty then it works ok.

But if `name` is empty then it doesn't fetch everything. Instead it fetches nothing.

Currently I have to create two separate NSPredicates to bypass this behavior, but it gets complicated very quickly when there are multiple string values to filter.

For instance:

```
if name.isNotEmpty {
    predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name CONTAINS %@ AND summary = %@", name, summary)
} else {
    predicate = NSPredicate(format: "summary = %@", summary)
}
```

And then use that predicate for fetch requests.

Another option I have tried is to simply fetch everything and then filter it using the `string.contains()` function.

However, I would like to avoid returning too many records from my fetch requests if possible.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I like to work with NSCompoundPredicate instead of using “AND” and this also makes it easier to build a predicate dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also use [`NSCompoundPredicate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscompoundpredicate) as suggested by [@Joakim Danielson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9223839/joakim-danielson) in [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75954652/nspredicate-contains-but-only-when-not-empty#comment133969389_75954652) to handle that behavior:

You jut need to isolate which needs to use AND/OR in case you use multiple logic:

```
var predicates: [NSPredicate] = []

predicate.append(defaultPredicate1)
predicate.append(defaultPredicate2)
...
if condition1 {
    predicate.append(conditionPredicate1)
}
if condition2 {
    predicate.append(conditionPredicate2)
}
...

let finalPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: predicates)
```

With your simple case:

```
var predicates: [NSPredicate] = []

predicates.append(NSPredicate(format: "summary = %@", summary))

if name.isNotEmpty {
    predicate.append(NSPredicate(format: "name CONTAINS %@)", name))
}

let finalPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: predicates)
```